# How do I fix the error "Your personal site does not contain a picture library named 'Pictures'" on user profile pages?

Tags: user-profile-service, profile-sync, my-profile

I'm working with a SharePoint 2010 farm that has SP 1 + the October 2011 CU installed. MySites and User Profile Synchronization with Active Directory were recently added. Everything seems to be working fine with the exception of loading user pictures. On the user profile page, when they click "Choose Picture," they get the error "Your personal site does not contain a picture library named 'Pictures'" on the Upload dialog. Does anyone have some insite on how to correct this problem?

Comment: This may be an issue caused by the October 2011 CU (I haven't confirmed this link so I'm not using it as an answer): http://sharepoint.nauplius.net/2011/11/october-2011-cu-breaks-user-profile.html

Comment: Ouch. So that looks like there is no immediate fix. Looks like we wait for MS to patch or we roll back the Oct update. I'm not looking forward to either.

Comment: You can't roll back updates, so it if really is an issue introduced by the CU (it's not listed on the KB) you'll have to wait.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has confirmed this bug in the Oct 2011 cumulative update. According to [this MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/calvarro/archive/2011/12/08/sharepoint-server-2010-amp-mysite-exception-your-personal-site-does-not-contain-a-picture-library-named-pictures.aspx) the fix should be included in the Dec 2011 cumulative update and should be released around December 27th.

Answer (score 2):

I've validated that this is resolved in the SharePoint Dec 2011 CU.  Also, uploading pictures for other users via Central Admin has been fixed, which was purposefully broken in the June CU.  You can find the links to the Dec CU updates [here](http://sharepoint.nauplius.net/2011/12/sharepoint-2010-december-2011.html).

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft changed the name from Pictures to "User Photos" in the October CU and the December CU does not fix the problem.  They didn't update the error message either, so it still says it's looking for Pictures, but it's really looking for "User Photos".  You can confirm this by looking at the code for the upload control in reflector.

Create a Picture library called "Users Photos" and your problems should disappear.

Comment: I tried every possible CU but didnt help at all. i created Picture libary named Pictures and i can not created User Photos because it already has libary named User Photos i am stucked for 3 days now. I am now using Sharepoint 2010 with sp1 + febuary 2012 cu Thanks for you help